# Is "ChildActionOnly" needed for controller with "Authorize"?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Is "ChildActionOnly" needed in a use like the code example below?

```
[Authorize]
public class HomeController
{

 [ChildActionOnly]
 public ActionResult HomeAuthContent()
 {
    return PartialView("_AuthContent");
 }
}
```

Authorize correct if "ChildActionOnly" is removed?

Comment: Authorize and ChildActionOnly are two different things for different purpose. What purpose you are looking for?

Comment: "HomeAuthContent()" I call this method with Ajax.  I don't want the user to be accessed from outside.